# How to assign options to a variable?

Tags: syntax, options, assignment

I want to redefine a function similar to `Plot` like this:

```
newPlot[func_, range_, prop___] := Plot[func, range, prop, GridLines -> something, 
                                        FrameStyle -> something]
```

To be more flexible, I'd like to write it more in the following way:

```
moreProp = GridLines -> something, FrameStyle -> something
newPlot[func_, range_, prop___] := Plot[func, range, prop, moreProp]
```

Unfortunately it's not working. 
What's the necessary syntax than for `moreProp`

I just edited the question for more clarification (I hope).

Comment: `SetOptions` ... ?

Comment: Not really what I was looking for

Comment: Use `moreProp = {GridLines -> something, FrameStyle -> something}`

Comment: I tried that, it's not working this way I guess...

Comment: @Kay `moreprops = {Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic};
newPlot[func_, range_, prop___] := 
  With[{mp = moreprops}, Plot[func, range, prop, mp]];
newPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed]` still works

Comment: Wow, finally :D thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one aspect of a classic problem: [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). So, `moreProp` is not being evaluated. I think the most effective way to work around this is to use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) (cf. this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/52)) to inject the values into `Plot`, e.g.

```
newPlot[func_, range_, prop___] := 
 With[{mp = moreProp}, Plot[func, range, prop, mp]]
```

Then, it works:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
newPlot2[func_, range_, prop___] := Plot[func, range, prop, #] & @ moreProp
```

which performs a similar injection.

As was pointed out in the comments, `Plot` accepts lists of options, so the above methods work. But, if `Plot` did not do this, you could use one of the following two methods:

```
newPlot3[func_, range_, prop__] := 
 With[{mp = Sequence@@Flatten[{prop, moreProp}]},
  Plot[func, range, mp]
 ]
```

or

```
newPlot4[func_, range_, prop__] := 
  Plot[func, range, prop, ##]& @@ Flatten[{moreProp}]
```

Comment: Seems is not working, when `moreProp` consists of more than one property like `GridLines -> something, FrameStyle -> something, etc.`

Comment: @Kay `newPlot[func_, range_, prop___] := 
  With[{mp = {Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic}}, 
   Plot[func, range, prop, mp]];
newPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed]` works for me.

Comment: @BlacKow Indeed, you are right. I forgot to cramp the options... However, I'm not happy with the fact, that I have to assign dozens of Options to every redefiniton. Therefore I was hoping to do it like to assign something to a variable... I just edited my question to be a bit more clear hopefully

Comment: @Kay you can reset what `moreProp` is set to. Try `moreProp = {GridLines -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Blue, Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}}` and then `moreProp = {PlotStyle -> Red}` and run `newPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]` after each change. You'll see that it updates the values.

Comment: Luckily `Plot[]` accepts a list of options; for some other functions, using `Sequence[]` might be necessary.

Comment: @J.M. true. But, the number of functions that do not is decreasing. However, that is a good point, expanded the code.